# Download file on iOS using POST request and iframe

Tags: ios, post, download

I'm trying to get file downloading to iOS device by POSTing, because I can't use normal GET download for security reasons. This is simplified example:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form target="_self" method="post" target="ifr" action="script.php">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <iframe name="ifr" id="ifr" src="about:blank"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

script.php sends binary data in response to POST.

This works in all browsers and android devices, but iOS falters. Does anyone know any workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any framework to do POST requests? 
I got similar problem when I was using AFNetworking v2.0. There is known issue with new 2.0 version. Changing framework back to AFNetworking 1.0 resolved my problem.

Comment: No framework is used. Are you encounteing this issue with AFNetworking  2.0 on all devices or iOS only?